# Subquery returns more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, subquery

```
SELECT [Acc_DocumentNo],[Acc_DocumentDate],[Acc_DocumentType],[Acc_DocumentRef],[Acc_DocumentAmount],
    [Acc_CustomerID],[Acc_DebtorGroupID],[Acc_DebtorBranchID],
    (SELECT Acc_ManualReferenceNo
        FROM Acc_CreditDocuments
        WHERE Acc_DocumentNo IN 
        (SELECT Acc_DocumentRef FROM Acc_CreditDocuments 
    WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @DocumentNo)) As [Acc_ManualReferenceNo],
        [Acc_Status],[Acc_CreatedBy],[Acc_CreatedAt],[Acc_ModifiedBy],[Acc_ModifiedAt]
FROM Acc_CreditDocuments
WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @DocumentNo AND
Acc_DocumentRef <> Acc_DocumentNo
```

In above query, subquery statement for selecting `Acc_ManualReferenceNo` returns more than one value if it has more than one `DocumentNo`.

Can I open db cursor to fetch and insert the values one by one? Or is there any other way to do it?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` the table with itself instead, like this:

```
SELECT 
  a1.[Acc_DocumentNo],
  a1.[Acc_DocumentDate],
  a1.[Acc_DocumentType],
  a1.[Acc_DocumentRef],
  a1.[Acc_DocumentAmount],
  a1.[Acc_CustomerID],
  a1.[Acc_DebtorGroupID],
  a1.[Acc_DebtorBranchID],
  a2.Acc_ManualReferenceNo As [Acc_ManualReferenceNo] -- < --
  ...
FROM Acc_CreditDocuments AS a1
INNER JOIN Acc_CreditDocuments AS a2 ON a1.cc_DocumentRef = a2.Acc_DocumentNo
WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @DocumentNo 
  AND a1.Acc_DocumentRef <> a1.Acc_DocumentNo
```

Comment: I was thinking the solution for my problem for the whole morning and you solved it in a few minutes after my question was posted. I didn't get an idea of using INNER JOIN in this case. You are so great. Thanks.

Comment: @Jowie - You're welcome any time, glad I could help :) But please read about `JOIN`s.